# Get resources across all namespaces by name - clusterrole vs all other resources

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

May be the wrong forum for such a question, but I am wondering why:

```
k get daemonsets.apps sysdig-agent -A
```

returns:

```
error: a resource cannot be retrieved by name across all namespaces
```

while

```
k get clusterrole sysdig-agent -A
```

returns:

```
NAME           CREATED AT
sysdig-agent   2019-05-28T08:04:01Z
```

I actually didn't think you could search by name across all namespaces with any object type - I am surprised it works for clusterrole, wondering what the reason is behind this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `ClusterRole` does not have a namespace, and thus the server just silently discarded your `-A` query for that resource type